# How to get validation status from JSF component

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jsf-2

I want set a special error class to div block into my custom component for JSF. I want set errorClass to "error" if this field failed the validation.

```
<c:if test="${?????}">
    <c:set var="errorClass" value="error" />    
</c:if>

<div class="input ${errorClass}">
    <label for="#{rich:clientId('input')}:input">#{cc.attrs.label}</label>
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
        <cc:insertChildren />
    </h:inputText>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `component.valid` inside the style or styleClass attribute of your inputText:

```html
<h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" 
             styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'error'}" />
```

However, this won't work in your `div` since it is no jsf component. You could try component binding (from theory, not tested):

```html
<div class="#{myComponent.valid ? '' : 'error'}">
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" binding="#{myComponent}">
        <cc:insertChildren />
    </h:inputText>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not work. Maybe there is a way to place <h:message ...> into <c:if test='...'> ?

Comment: This is a different requirement. But what exaclty did not work, the first or the second example or both? What happens?

Comment: I put this code into page: 
   <h:inputText value="#{userBean.text}" required="true" styleClass="#{inputText.valid ? '' : 'error'}" />
but 'error' has been always present.

Comment: You have to use `component.valid` instead of `inputText.valid`. `component` is an implicit el object the points to the current jsf component.