# JSF component object

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6

There are many tutorials on the internet where component object on JSF page is used.
Usually component.clientId or component.valid are used.
Example

```
<h:inputText .... styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'ui-input-invalid'}"/>
```

If i create page with such component, i get an error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: 
The class 'javax.faces.component.UIPanel' does not have the property 'valid'.
```

I googled that for inputText should be there UIInput class (which has isValid method), but i have there UIPanel (which dasn't).

Any idea why is there UI Panel?
(Java EE 6, JSF 2.1, Weblogic 12.1.2)

Comment: What version of JSF are you using? The `component` implicit object does not have a `valid` attribute in my version (2.2)

Comment: Now i use JSF 2.1. I've seen it e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559460/how-to-get-validation-status-from-jsf-component).

Comment: `component` [**does not have a `valid` attribute**](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html). I don't know what the answer you linked is talking about, but there's nothing in the API to back it up

Comment: You are right, but have alook on [BalusC explanation](http://balusc.blogspot.sk/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects) >>The #{component} of a <h:inputText> component refers to an instance of UIInput class which in turn has an isValid() method.

Comment: Ok. You have the article and the API. Take your pick.

Comment: I have similar problem, you can see what worked in my case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476793/implicit-expression-language-object-component-not-working-in-jsf-2-2-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not a single component is valid is irrelevant in the long run; the entire request will be marked as invalid, even if it's as a result of the failure of a single component.

You should be retrieving the status of a request on the `facesContext` implicit EL object

```
<h:inputText .... styleClass="#{facesContext.validationFailed ? '' : 'ui-input-invalid'}"/>
```

---

Nothing I've seen in the 2.1 or 2.2 API supports the the presence of a `valid` attribute for the `component` implicit EL object. It's an implementation of `javax.faces.component.UIComponent`

Reference:

- [UIComponent Javadoc](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html)