# Implicit expression language object "component" not working in jsf 2.2.6

Tags: validation, jsf-2, el, jsf-2.2, implicit

I'm migrating a jsf 2.0 application to jsf 2.2.6. There is a extensive use of implicit EL object **component** as styleClass="#{component.valid?'':'err'}".

In jsf 2.2.6 (jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar) valid is not recognized, throwing "ServletException: The class 'javax.faces.component.html.xxx' does not have the property 'valid".

Is this functionality deprecated in jsf 2.x.x?

Can be related to JBoss EL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the reason of the exception. The problem was that I had a comment in the code containing "component.valid". Removing the comment resolves the problem.

```
<!-- styleClass="#{component.valid ? '': 'err' }" -->
```

It's tricky. The exception was not clear about the line of code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you trying the `component.valid` on element that does not support it at all, for example the [h:panelGroup](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlPanelGroup.html) does not have the *isValid* getter , while [h:inputText](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputText.html) does.

A workaround could be to *abuse* the validation status of another element in your page in order to apply the styleClass of another, see example:

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{myComponent.valid ? '' : 'error'}">
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{myBean.myValue}" binding="#{myComponent}">
    </h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup >
```